# Предупреждение из-за тернарной операции в C (DOS)

Tags: char, dos, c, условия

Компилятор (QC2 под DOSBox) выдаёт варнинги `data conversion` если переменной типа `char` присваивать значение, вычисляемое тернарным оператором.

Код для примера:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char str[33];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        str[i] = (i % 2 == 0) ? '0' : '1';
    }
    str[32] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", str);


}
```

Варнинг в строке: `str[i] = (i % 2 == 0) ? '0' : '1';`

В чём может быть проблема? Есть возможность исправить?

Обычными условными операторами неудобно пользоваться из-за того, что выходит несколько вложенных тернарных операторов.

UPD:
Компилятор gcc mingw варнингов не выдаёт.

UPD2:
@alexlz

> а опубликовать эти секретные варнинги никак нельзя?

В комментариях отвечал - `warning C4051: data conversion`

Comment: А приведите плиз полный текст сообщения?

Кстати, ваша строка не содержит финального 0, немедленно исправьте, пока никто не заметил.

Comment: `warning C4051: data conversion`

>Кстати, ваша строка не содержит финального 0, немедленно исправьте, пока никто не заметил.

Случайно вместо `\0` написал `\n` (по привычке, видимо), исправил.

Comment: может быть на этом странном компиляторе тип char (а он может быть как знаковый, так и беззнаковый) не совпадает с типом символа, записанного в виде `'0'`. Попробуйте перед char дописать signed/unsigned и посмотреть, как он среагирует.

Comment: @KoVadim, безрезультатно. Всегда одно и то же предупреждение.

Comment: а если переписать красивее

    // === skip ===
    char * letter = "01";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        str[i] = letter[i % 2];
    }
    // === skip ===

Comment: @KoVadim: Если мне не изменяет память, в C по стандарту символьные константы имеют тип `int`.

Comment: @froxxendsg: А если написать так:

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        char c = (i % 2 == 0) ? '0' : '1';
        str[i] = c;
    }

— то на какую их строк ругается?

Comment: @froxxendsg а как, собственно ругается-то? Говорит-то что?

@VladD

         for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) str[i] = (i % 2 == 0) + '0';

Comment: или так:
    str[i] = '0' + i % 2;

Comment: @KoVadim
>а если переписать красивее

Присваиваться будут различные символы (псевдографика), код лишь для примера

@VladD 
>А если написать так — то на какую из строк ругается?

Ругается именно на строку с присвоением переменной типа `char` значения, вычисляемого тернарным оператором:

    char c = (i % 2 == 0) ? '0' : '1';

@alexlz
>а как, собственно ругается-то? Говорит-то что?

Выдаёт варнинги, но программа выводит всё правильно (но с варнингами никак нельзя)

Comment: Может вовсе не в этой строчке дело?? gcc при компиляции ругается на другое :  
gcc -o test main.c -Wall 
main.c:4: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int'

Comment: @froxxendsg: уже интересно. А как насчёт простого

    char c = '0';

?

Comment: @margosh, точно не из-за этого.

@VladD, обычное присваивание символа без проблем компилируется. К слову, если присваивать результат тернарной операции к переменной, например, типа `int`, то проблем тоже не возникает.

--------------

@VladD, к сожалению, лимит комментариев..
*Ответ на комментарий ниже:*
Ещё интересный случай:

    str[i] = (1) ? '0' : '1';

В таком случае тоже варнингов нет, варнинги появляются, когда в условии есть переменные. Без понятия, почему так.

Comment: @froxxendsg: Странно: чем для него отличается

    char c = '0';

от

    char c = (i % 2 == 0) ? '0' : '1';

? В обоих случаях справа выражение типа `int`.

Comment: В C символьные литералы имеют тип int, отсюда и warning.

Comment: @dzhioev: это да, но почему же тогда код `char c = '0';` не выдаёт warning?

Comment: @froxxendsg а опубликовать эти секретные варнинги никак нельзя?

Comment: @VladD, вероятно там срабатывает какая-то оптимизация при компиляции и он знает, что переполнение не возникнет. А для выражения с переменной он этого вывести не может.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Думаю, это проблема устаревшего компилятора. Современный компилятор никаких сообщений не выдаёт: http://ideone.com/hHUGdA

Comment: @VladD, http://ideone.com/ygWoVI и http://codepad.org/VKOTylTv - тут тоже предупреждения нет. Си же принципиально не проверяет переполнение. Просто автор откапал какой-то мутный компилятор, который решил-таки сужающее приведение проверить... Но не смог.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Короче, ошибка судя по всему из-за старого компилятора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найденное (казалось бы, очевидное) решение:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char str[33];
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        str[i] = (char)( (i % 2 == 0) ? '0' : '1' );
    }
    str[32] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Он рассматривает значение как int, а не как char. При желании можно добавить яное приведение типа. Но вообще, с каких пор в си есть предупреждения на подобные преобразования?

А само выражение я бы перепивал так:

```
str[i] = '0' + (i&1);
```

Кстати, какая-то странная программа. Это потом дожно стать формированием бинарного представления числа?

Comment: >>Кстати, какая-то странная программа.<< -- это лишь пример был, в условии тернарной операции не обязательно должно было быть `i % 2 == 0`, могло быть, например, `i % 6 == 0`, и элементу массива не обязательно присваивались `0` или `1`, соотв. запись `str[i] = '0' + (i&1);` не получилось бы использовать. А вообще, программа выводила таблицу на псевдографике.